# Why are sqlite3 shortcut functions called "nonstandard"?

Tags: python, sqlite

I've used sqlite3 in Python in which `execute()` creates ambiguity. When I use:

```py
import sqlite3
A = sqlite3.connect('a')
A.execute('command to be executed')
help(A.execute)
```

I got the output of help() as:

```
.....
.....
Executes a SQL statement. Non-standard.
```

But when I execute like this:

```py
import sqlite3
A = sqlite.connect('a').cursor()
A.execute('command to be executed')
help(A.execute)
```

I got the output of help() as:

```
.....
.....
Executes a SQL statement.
```

My doubt is what does **Non-standard** refer to? Even the Python documentation provides these words [`execute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) for `execute()`, `executemany()`, and `executescript()` in connection objects.

I've even searched in web about nonstandard shortcuts in Python. But I didn't get any relevant information. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "nonstandard" function is the `execute` method of the [`sqlite3.Connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.execute) class:

> This is a nonstandard shortcut that creates a cursor object by calling the `cursor()` method, calls the cursor’s `execute()` method with the parameters given, and returns the cursor.

"Standard" refers to *PEP 249 -- Python Database API Specification v2.0* which the `sqlite3` module follows. It does not specify an `execute` method for the [`Connection`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#connection-objects) class, but the `sqlite3` module provides it anyway, that's why it is called "nonstandard".

PEP 249 only specifies the `execute` method of the [`Cursor`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) class, which the `sqlite3` module [implements](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute), of course.